# How to install extenstion language "bahasa indonesia" on openchart 3.0.2.0? I use xampp on linux ubuntu 18.04

Tags: opencart

[i already installed language extensions "bahasa indonesia"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1AG7.png)i can't install extensions language "bahasa indonesia" on openchart 3.0.2.0.

[but still, my extension can't show up on my project opencart :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaBvO.png)

How to install extenstion language "bahasa indonesia" on openchart 3.0.2.0? I use xampp on linux ubuntu 18.04. I already uploaded language extension file  "BAHASA INDONESIA OPENCART 3.0.2.0.zip". But i can't get my extension.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=cms/blog/info&blog_id=227)?

Comment: i already try that tutorial buddy. but still doesn't work for me. :(